# sort object then subsort further - javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, object

okay so i have an object created like this:

```
object = {};

object.set_1.date = <date object or unix time stamp>
object.set_1.day = "Sunday";
object.set_1.total = 12;

object.set_2.date = <date object or unix time stamp>
object.set_2.day = "Sunday";
object.set_2.total = 19;

object.set_3.date = <date object or unix time stamp>
object.set_3.day = "Monday";
object.set_3.total = 15;
```

and so fourth.

Is there a way to sort these objects by day, and then sort each day by total?

I'm sure theres multiple different ways to achieve this. Could any one help with this? what would be the best way to do it?.

Comment: If you place individual objects into array and just have 3 objects with 3 properties (instead of 1 object with 9 properties) then Array.Sort can accept a custom sorting function which you can implement howerer you want

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Let's take a more in-depth look at what @YuriyGalanter said. Let's begin with a little restructuring:

**New Structure**

Modify your old object with nine properties to be an array containing three objects with three properties:

```
objArray = [
    {
        "date": <date object or unix time stamp>,
        "day": "Sunday",
        "total": 12
    },
    {
        "date": <date object or unix time stamp>,
        "day": "Sunday",
        "total": 19
    },
    {
        "date": <date object or unix time stamp>,
        "day": "Monday",
        "total": 15
    }
];
```

**Advantages of this Approach**

You gain a few things by having the above approach. For one, readability. It is much easier to read and understand where each object begins and ends and to understand which objects encompass which properties. Secondly, this is going to make sorting with JavaScript a breeze. The built in `.sort()` function can take an optional parameter - A Function - that defines a custom sort "algorithm" for lack of a better word. Let's take a look at that:

**Custom JavaScript Sort**

```
objArray.sort(function (objA, objB) {
    var dayA = (objA.day).toLowerCase();
    var dayB = (objB.day).toLowerCase();

    // Sort first on day
    if(dayA > dayB) {
        return 1;
    } else if (dayA < dayB) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        // If the days are the same,
        // do a nested sort on total.
        var totalA = objA.total;
        var totalB = objB.total;

        if(totalA > totalB) {
            return 1;
        } else if (totalA < totalB) {
            return -1;
        } else {
            return 0;
        }
    }
});
```

The above nested sort algorithm can be extended, simply by adding your next sort criteria in place of the `return 0;` and continuing on. This should get you started in the right direction.

Good luck and happy coding!

Comment: Yay! thanks so much! i just started to try something like this (with much less knowledge on the matter.. even googling didnt help me too much)

Comment: @DustinSilk Not a problem buddy. Glad to help. It was actually really good timing on your part. I wrote a very similar custom sort just a few days ago for a project I'm working on now so it was still fresh in the ole brain.

Comment: There may be an even easier way. If you create a string from the properties you want to sort on, in the order you want to sort, then you can do simple string comparison. Not sure how this would deal with special chars though.

I don't think this question should have been closed.